# React Navigation - pass state as a prop from controlled component to another component

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Using the React Navigation library, I would like to pass the state from a controlled component as a prop to another component for display. However, I can't seem to achieve this with either the React Navigation library or React Router from React Training (StackNavigator). Below is my code using React Navigation:

```
// root component
class HomeScreen extends Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    // no state yet
  };
}

    render() {

    return(
      <View></View>
    )
  }
} 

// stack navigation
const MyApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: Home },
  A: { screen: A },
  B: { screen: B },
  C: { screen: C },
  D: { screen: D },
}, 


// controlled component getting user input and saving as state
class B extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {
        page:'B',
        query: '',
        showTextInput: true,
        showSearchResults: true,
        showSearchAgain: false,
        userSelection: '',
      }
    };

// other code in this component is receiving input as state query, 
matching it with a set of search terms, and taking the selection and 
setting it as state userSelection - all successfully

// the button in this code successfully navigates to component C - 
the only question is how to pass state userSelection to C? 
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigate('C')}>
  <View style={styles.button}>
    <View style={styles.buttonTextAlign}>
       <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
          Button
       </Text>
    </View>
  </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

How do I pass the state userSelection in component B to component C? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send parameters while navigating to other screens. Detailed info can be found in [react-navigation docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-prop#navigate-Link-to-other-screens).

**Example**

```
<Button
    onPress={() => navigate('C', {name: 'Brent'})}
    title="Go to Brent's profile"
/>

// and in your C Component
console.log(this.props.navigation.state.params.name) // logs Brent
```

Comment: Thanks so much it worked! Had to do `<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigate('C', {userSelection: this.state.userSelection})}>`

Comment: are you also familiar with how to do this in React Router v4? I'm really stuck [here too.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46308858/react-router-v4-cannot-pass-state-as-prop-via-link?noredirect=1#comment79581760_46308858)