# React Router v4 - Cannot pass state as prop via <Link>

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Trying to use React Router v4 on the web to pass state from Component A as a prop to Component B. The following code returns this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property "state" of undefined." I removed all the component creation lines for brevity:

```
// Component A

state = {
    selectedCountry: 'Gambia',
}

console.log(this.state.selectedCountry) // returns Gambia

// this is where it fails to pass state
<Link to={{ 
    pathname: '/component-b', // correct path
    state: { selectedCountry: this.state.selectedCountry }
}}>
    <button className="button">Button</button>
</Link>



// Component B

componentWillMount() {

// not received, sadly undefined
console.log(this.props.location.state.selectedCountry)

}
```

What am I missing here? Many thanks!

**EDIT 1:** Tried suggestion to initialize prop outside , but received same error of undefined

```
// Component A
const selectedCountryProp = {
            pathname: '/trip-cards-container',
            state: { selectedCountry: this.state.selectedCountry }
        } 

return (
    <Link to={ selectedCountryProp }/>  
    {console.log(selectedCountryProp.state.selectedCountry)} 
    // logs expected Gambia
       <button className="button">Button</button>
    </Link>
    )

// Component B
componentWillMount() {
    console.log(this.props.location.state.selectedCountry)
    // logs cannot receive property of state of undefined
    // also tried with this.props.location.selectedCountryProp...
    // but logs cannot receive property of selectedCountryProp of
    // undefined
}
```

Comment: what do you see if you try ```console.log('this.props')``` ?

Comment: If I do that I get `this.props`, but if I set it to `console.log(this.props)` I get `[object Object]`

Comment: i think `this` is not referring to the right context. try initializing the object outside `Link` -> ```const linkProp = { ... } <Link to={ linkProp } />```

Comment: @ReiDien thanks for the suggestion! I gave it a try but am still receiving an undefined error - I think it may have something to do with how the prop is being received via `this.props.location.state.selectedCountry`. I'll append what I tried above

Comment: I'm having the same issue ! Can't find anything online to resolve this !!
Have you found*any* useful hacks ??

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're loading component B separately? e.g. refreshing the same route. If you're navigating from A you have to navigate to B from A every time.